# My I recycle an SSD from a tablet pc and install it on a laptop and is it recommendable?

Tags: ssd, adapter, tablet-pc

I hold a Dell Venue Pro 11 7130 with a 128 GB SSD (the drive can be extracted) and a portable workingstation (laptop) with a 60 GB SSD. I would like to substitute the latter with the SSD installed on the tablet pc, internally.

I wonder if this operation might be possible by exploiting an internal adapter, if any.
If yes, I wonder if it might imply performance lags in the workingstation or any other issue.

Comment: Is the SSD from the tablet just a SATA connection and a standard 2.5" drive?

Comment: this one: http://www.notebookcheck.it/fileadmin/Notebooks/Dell/Venue_11_Pro_7140/Dell_Venue_7140_62.jpg

Comment: So you have an m.2 SSD in you tablet, which does use a SATA connection. Now the question will be, does your laptop support m.2 SSD's? What laptop model is it?

Comment: the laptop is this-> http://www.santech.eu/m58-series

Comment: I can't definitively say if your laptop supports an m.2 SSD without using an adapter like [this](https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-2-5in-Adapter-Converter-SAT32M225/dp/B00ITJ7U20). If you buy an adapter like this, you will be able to use your m.2 SSD in your laptop.

Comment: @robertalrp, aside from the hardware compatibility, be aware that you may need to do some OS cleanup, like loading appropriate drivers for the different hardware. You probably won't be able to simply plug it in, boot from it, and use it as if it was still in the tablet.  Also, if the OS on the drives are OEM Windows, you may need to deal with license issues.

Comment: @fixer1234 license is retail. I installed a second internal hdd in the same machine (I use it for storage and desktop apps), no need to install drivers in that case...